# Instance of JsonNode always receive null when I will get array of fields

Tags: android, json, delphi, jackson, datasnap

In my Android Application the variable enderecos of String type receives an json array from my Datasnap Server:

```json
[
   "{\"type\":\"ClassesProjeto.TEndereco\",\"id\":1,\"fields\":{\"FIdentificador_Endereco\":1,\"FRua\":\"Test\",\"FNumero\":\"1\",\"FCidade\":\"Test\",\"FBairro\":\"Test\",\"FEstado\":\"Test\",\"FVersao_Dispositivo\":1}}",
   "{\"type\":\"ClassesProjeto.TEndereco\",\"id\":1,\"fields\":{\"FIdentificador_Endereco\":2,\"FRua\":\"Test2\",\"FNumero\":\"1\",\"FCidade\":\"Test2\",\"FBairro\":\"Test2\",\"FEstado\":\"Test2\",\"FVersao_Dispositivo\":1}}"
]
```

And I use the following code to get the JSON values from each object from this array:

```
enderecos = dsProxy.getEnderecos();

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = objectMapper.readTree(enderecos);
    for (JsonNode node_object : node){
         JsonNode object = node_object.get("fields");
}
```

But the variable node of JsonNode always receives null, why? And the property fields exists in each Json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the correct formatting of your JSON we all can see, the there is a JSON array containing **2 string value elements**.

```json
[
   "{\"type\":\"ClassesProjeto.TEndereco\",\"id\":1,\"fields\":{\"FIdentificador_Endereco\":1,\"FRua\":\"Test\",\"FNumero\":\"1\",\"FCidade\":\"Test\",\"FBairro\":\"Test\",\"FEstado\":\"Test\",\"FVersao_Dispositivo\":1}}",
   "{\"type\":\"ClassesProjeto.TEndereco\",\"id\":1,\"fields\":{\"FIdentificador_Endereco\":2,\"FRua\":\"Test2\",\"FNumero\":\"1\",\"FCidade\":\"Test2\",\"FBairro\":\"Test2\",\"FEstado\":\"Test2\",\"FVersao_Dispositivo\":1}}"
]
```

These elements are representing each a JSON string which has to be parsed to get a JSON object.

- First element RAW

  ```
  "{\"type\":\"ClassesProjeto.TEndereco\",\"id\":1,\"fields\":{\"FIdentificador_Endereco\":1,\"FRua\":\"Test\",\"FNumero\":\"1\",\"FCidade\":\"Test\",\"FBairro\":\"Test\",\"FEstado\":\"Test\",\"FVersao_Dispositivo\":1}}"
  ```
- first element as JSON

  ```json
  {
     "type":"ClassesProjeto.TEndereco",
     "id":1,
     "fields":{
        "FIdentificador_Endereco":1,
        "FRua":"Test",
        "FNumero":"1",
        "FCidade":"Test",
        "FBairro":"Test",
        "FEstado":"Test",
        "FVersao_Dispositivo":1
     }
  }
  ```

To access the values as you do in your code the returned JSON should have been like this

```json
[
   {
      "type":"ClassesProjeto.TEndereco",
      "id":1,
      "fields":{
         "FIdentificador_Endereco":1,
         "FRua":"Test",
         "FNumero":"1",
         "FCidade":"Test",
         "FBairro":"Test",
         "FEstado":"Test",
         "FVersao_Dispositivo":1
      }
   },
   {
      "type":"ClassesProjeto.TEndereco",
      "id":1,
      "fields":{
         "FIdentificador_Endereco":2,
         "FRua":"Test2",
         "FNumero":"1",
         "FCidade":"Test2",
         "FBairro":"Test2",
         "FEstado":"Test2",
         "FVersao_Dispositivo":1
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: Thank you @Sir Rufo, I tried to convert the JSON String values to JSON Object but the variable receives {}, empty, I will fix it in the server to receive the JSON Array with the JSON Objects and not the JSON Array with JSON Strings.